# How to find a file which can't be found on macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, big-sur

After updating to the latest version of macOS Big Sur, I've noticed strange system behavior. Now while opening the system I'm getting a popup where there is the information:

> The file can't be found.

[image]

I want to file this file, but the difficultly about it is, I cannot find out what file is the problem about, or at least narrow the problem to the program or location, where I should look for it.

Any tips on how narrow the problem would be appreciated.

PS. Clicking the question mark icon is not helping, opening a blank page without any content.

Comment: How did you search for files?  What did you use?

Comment: Is it possibly a system file? These are stored on a separate volume and are a bit tricky to modify with the new Signed System Volume that Apple has introduced. I'm not sure how SSV works (yet). Also, you say this happens when the Mac boots up? If so, I'd try create a separate user account and see if it replicates on a fresh user account when you log in. If it doesn't happen on the new user account, you might have a login item that's causing the issue.

Comment: @jmh the point is I could not find any information _what_ file could not be found, therefore I could not make any research. I would look something in logs but I would need to know the place where this kind of error is logged.

Comment: I am getting the same thing. Two of these pop up. I did some troubleshooting and found it happens as soon as I plug my iPhone into one of the USB ports. It happens even with auto sync off. I have not been able to figure out why it's happening yet.

Comment: What specific steps do you take that happens when “opening the system” happens? It’s not clear what you do to make this appear...

Answer (score 1):

I see the exact same thing. I noted the time (09:35:25) and found this in Console:

```
Nov 14 09:35:24 Honu amsaccountsd[673]: objc[673]: Class AMSDaemonConnectionInterface is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleMediaServices.framework/Versions/A/AppleMediaServices and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleMediaServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/amsaccountsd. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Nov 14 09:35:24 Honu amsaccountsd[673]: objc[673]: Class AMSXDProtoMessage is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleMediaServices.framework/Versions/A/AppleMediaServices and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleMediaServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/amsaccountsd. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Nov 14 09:35:25 Honu MRT[674]: getattrlist failed for : #2: No such file or directory
Nov 14 09:35:29 --- last message repeated 2 times ---

Nov 14 09:35:29 Honu mdsync[694]: objc[694]: Class MDSPathFilter is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata and /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mdsync. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Nov 14 09:35:30 Honu com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]
```

So it seems to have to do with something called "getattrlist".

Here's a link that might be of help:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/getattrlist.2.html

That said, I still don't really know what this is but now I now know that I'm not the only one with this issue.

I know that this is likely not much help. If I find out more, I will post back.

Comment: getattrlist is trying to get the attributes of a file but the path is wrong or the file has been deleted.  OR, the path/file is misspelled in the app that called getattrlist.  The process that called getattrlist is MRT, and the PID of 674 suggests that it is one of the process started during boot.  This may or may not be the same issue as OP has.

Comment: MRT is the malware removal tool. Everything lines up if you installed software that starts at boot and the tool removed part of the program. If you make a brand new user account and log out of the affected account and into the new, does the errors how up there as well?